# How to find the correlation between rows of two tables with the same number of columns in R?

Tags: r, correlation

I have two distinct tables and want to find correlation between GeneQ in table2 and other Genes in table1 across 6 samples. How can I calculate and visual this correlation in R?

Thanks for any help.

Here is my table1

```
> dput(df1)

structure(list(Gene.name = c("GeneA", "GeneB", "GeneC", "GeneD"
), Sample1 = c(150L, 49L, 136L, 158L), Sample2 = c(322L, 13L, 
378L, 301L), Sample3 = c(84L, 95L, 66L, 75L), Sample4 = c(79L, 
86L, 71L, 63L), Sample5 = c(26L, 111L, 21L, 32L), Sample6 = c(103L, 
29L, 112L, 109L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))

> df1
  Gene.name Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5 Sample6
1     GeneA     150     322      84      79      26     103
2     GeneB      49      13      95      86     111      29
3     GeneC     136     378      66      71      21     112
4     GeneD     158     301      75      63      32     109
```

And table 2

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(Gene.name = "GeneQ", Sample1 = 52L, Sample2 = 18L, 
    Sample3 = 89L, Sample4 = 77L, Sample5 = 118L, Sample6 = 36L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))

> df2
Gene.name Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5 Sample6
1     GeneQ      52      18      89      77     118      36
```

Comment: you can calculate correlations by `as.vector(cor(t(df2[,-1]), t(df1[,-1])))`

Comment: Dear @det thanks for your reply, it worked. Can I have the p-value for each Gene as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
apply(df1,1,function(x) cor(as.numeric(x),as.numeric(df2)))
```